# How to get all values in SQL from a table's column, in QT C++

Tags: sqlite, qt, c++11

So I'm trying to get all of the values from a sqlite3 database in QT with C++ (11).
My table called "Auteurs", and the column that contains all the values called "nom".

The Whole table looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42ouf.png)

With DB Browser I successfully extracted all the values but implementing it into my program that accepted the the following syntax :

`Etudiants->exec(QLatin1String("SELECT nom FROM Auteurs WHERE nom is not NULL"));`

this only returns me the first value (in a form of QVariant) of the table and not the rest as well.
Any suggestion how to get all the values out and not just 1 from the table at a time?
In what sort of type I should store the values, that I will get (QStringList or something else)?

Other useful indications : Qt 5.14.1 (i386-little_endian-ilp32 shared (dynamic) release build;

by MSVC 2017) on
"windows" OS: Windows 8.1 Version 6.3 (Build 9600) [winnt version 6.3.9600]

Architecture: x86_64;

Thank you for your help !

Comment: ***without any error specification after compiling and executing the program tells me that it crashed. Any idea why it does ?*** You will have to use your debugger to figure that out.

Comment: Did check it. Got segmentation fault. Fixed it, and upon checking the returned value it only gives me the first value of the list and not the all of them in my program. Any further suggestions ? To make it clear I used the following commands to find the returned value : `Etudiants->exec(QLatin1String("SELECT nom FROM Auteurs WHERE nom is not NULL"));
    Etudiants->next();
    qDebug()<<Etudiants->value(0);`

Comment: In DB Browser using `SELECT nom FROM Auteurs WHERE nom is not NULL` returns all my values which is in my case 5 as there is 5 records stored in the table currently.

Comment: Are you sure `Etudiants` is properly initialized? Why is it a pointer at all? A QSqlQuery on the stack is perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes indeed it's properly initialized. And it is a pointer because I'm using it in other methods as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found the solution on my own.
All I had to do after executing
`Etudiants->exec(QLatin1String("SELECT nom FROM Auteurs WHERE nom is not NULL"));` is, do a loop with
`Etudiants->next();` in which i do each time a
`Etudiants->value(0).toString();` which i can simply store in a QStringList.